# disable the padding inside an html span element

Tags: html, css

How can I define a span such that its contents reach to the span's borders with no padding?
I have tried setting the padding on both the containing `div` and on the `span` itself to `'0'`, but this hasn't worked.

You can see in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sangil/yhhKL/1/) the number has whitespace all around it - especially on the top and bottom. This is what I am trying to eliminate - so that the span's borders actually touch the number.

Comment: You can't do anything about that. That is the fonts whitespace.

Comment: Not possible. There is no HTML padding, that white space you see is a part of the character set in the font.

Comment: anybody know why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The White space above the numbers is not caused by the padding, but instead it's caused by the fonts line height.

You can play around with a lineheight that is less than one, and it should give you the results you're looking for.

```
span {
    font-size: 64pt;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: .7;
}
```

Not quite perfect, but it'll change from font to font.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/yhhKL/16/)